# How to run web request (Observable) in `finalize()` or achieve similar behavior?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I want to somehow chain two web requests such that:

1. Request A (`Observable<void>`) is always run.
2. Request B (also `Observable<void>`) is also always run, after A and even when A completes with errors (like [`finalize()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/finalize)).
3. If A errors with E<sub>A</sub>, I want the whole pipeline to complete with E<sub>A</sub>.
4. If A succeeds, but B errors with E<sub>B</sub>, I want the whole pipeline to complete with E<sub>B</sub>.

   - I could also do with the pipeline just succeeding in this case.
5. If both error, then I want the whole pipeline to complete with E<sub>A</sub>.

---

This is the solution I could come up with, but it feels very clumsy:

```js
// Changes different parts of backend state in multiple steps,
// some of which might fail.
const reqA: Observable<void> = this.mutateSystemState();

// Loads & renders the system state, updating the parts that
// could be changed.
const reqB: Observable<void> = this.updateSystemStateDisplay();

const pipeline = reqA.pipe(
    catchError(e => of({ errA: e })),
    mergeMap(resultA => reqB.pipe(
        catchError(e => of({ errB: e })),
        map(resultB => {
            if (resultA instanceof Object) {
                throw resultA.errA;
            } else if (resultB instanceof Object) {
                throw resultB.errB;
            }
        })
    ))
);
```

Comment: I think it's the best you could write with the given contraints. I'd just improve the narrowing with `resultA && 'errA' in resultA` .

Comment: With TypeScript I could actually improve it to `if (resultA)` since `void` is falsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[onErrorResumeNext()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/onErrorResumeNext.ts)

whatever `reqA$` error or not, will subscribe `reqB$`

```
reqA$.pipe(
  onErrorResumeNext(reqB$)
).subscribe(...);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ps5f1j

---

```
const pipeline$ = of(reqA$, reqB$).pipe(
  concatMap(materialize()),
  filter(({kind}) => kind === 'E'), // filter Error
  reduce(identity), // collect then return first value
  dematerialize(),
);
```

or

```
const pipeline$ = of(reqA$, reqB$).pipe(
  concatMap(materialize()),
  max(({kind}) => +(kind === 'E')),
  dematerialize(),
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jnqhjw

Comment: Nice this works too and also avoids the nesting of `pipe()`. But I'm wondering: can't the `reduce(identity)` be omitted? In case both requests error and the pipeline has multiple error notifications then `dematerialize()` will stop at the first error already.

Comment: if you comment out `reduce(identity)`, when `reqA$` has error `reqB$` won't be subscribed, https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-3zmvcf

Comment: By the way, If you wanna behavior like this, just use `concat(reqA$, reqB$)`

Answer (score 2):

The [materialize](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/materialize) operator converts next, error, or completion 'events' into
[ObservableNotification](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/type-alias/ObservableNotification) objects.

Assuming you want `pipeline$` to either error or complete without emitting a value, you can do the following:

```js
const pipeline$ = reqA.pipe(
  materialize(),
  concatMap(a => reqB.pipe(
    materialize(),
    map(
      // Both have executed.
      // Both a & b are ObservableNotification objects
      // Emit a if ErrorNotification
      b => a.kind === 'E' ? a
      // Otherwise emit CompleteNotification if b is a NextNotification
        : b.kind === 'N' ? {kind: 'C'}
      // Otherwise emit b
        : b
    )
  )),
  // At this point, we've got reqA's ErrorNotification, reqB's ErrorNotification or a CompleteNotification.
  // Either way, this observable is closing before the first materialize gets a chance to emit reqA's CompleteNotification
  dematerialize()
);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for: an obscure operator that almost does all the work for you :D Gonna try it next week at work and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use `concatMap()` instead of `mergeMap()` here?

Comment: Theoretically yes but I admit that I didn't test my theory! I didn't want to worry about whether or not `reqB` might be... or later become... asynchronous. `reqA.pipe(materialize ())` emits either an ErrorNotification or a NextNotification **and** a CompleteNotification, so if you used `mergeMap` then `reqB` would be subcribed to twice, but with `concatMap`, `pipeline` will close before a CompleteNotification from `reqA` is dealt with. That's my theory, anyway. Instead of `concatMap(...)`, we could use `take(1),mergeMap(...)` and get the same result.